# Insert Selected ListView Content into txt file

Tags: java, txt

```java
try
{
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("student1.txt");
 
    myWriter.write(courseList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    myWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would like to add the selected ListView Content into txt file. The problem with the code above is at Line 3. I know that I can get the value of the selected item in the listview with `courseList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`. So I tried to insert `courseList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` into `myWriter.write()` at Line 3. But VS Code shows error when running the code above. May I know how to correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your situation. Keep in mind that i changed your `try` to    be try with resource so that you avoid the need of a `finally` block, which you had not added, although you should. Try with resources is a concept introduced in Java 7 and if you are using this version or newer, this is a recommended way of using a resource (like `FileWriter`)

```
try (FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("student1.txt"))
{
 
    String stringRepresentation = String.valueOf(courseList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    myWriter.write(stringRepresentation, 0, stringRepresentation.length());
    System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```